# Reducible fibers of the moment map of completely integrable system

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry

Let $M$ be a smooth projective variety of dimension $n$ over the complex numbers. Further assume that  the cotangent bundle $T^*M$ of $M$ is a completely integrable system with $n$ independent regular functions $f_1, ... f_n$ in involution. Then we have the moment map $\mu: T^*M \to \mathbb{C}^n$, given by $f_1, ..., f_n$. Let $Y \subset \mathbb{C}^n$ be the set of all elements $p \in \mathbb{C}^n$ such that $\mu^{-1}(p)$ is reducible.

Question:
What is the co-dimension of $Y$ ? Is it always $\ge 2$ ?

Comment: The zero-fiber of the momentum map induced by the $\mathbb C^*$-action on $\mathbb P^1_{\mathbb C}$ has three components: The zero section and the fibers over the fixed points.

Comment: If I have understood correctly, dimension of $Y$ need not be of codimension $2$ right ?  In your example I guess general fibers are irreducible. Can we say something in higher dimension ?

Comment: Can we say what in higher dimension? Did you look at smooth torus embeddings?

Comment: No. Could you please send me the reference ?

Comment: Can say the codimension of $Y$ is at least 2, when dimension of M is $\ge 3$?

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit too long for a comment:

Let $G=(\mathbb C^*)^n$ act on the affine space $\mathbb C^n$ in the usual way:
$$(t_1,\ldots,t_n)\cdot(q_1,\ldots,q_n)=(t_1q_1,\ldots,t_nq_n)$$
The cotangent bundle has coordinates $q_i$ and $p_i$ and the momentum map is
$$\mu:(q_1,\ldots,q_n,p_1,\ldots,p_n)\mapsto(q_1p_1,\ldots,q_np_n).$$
Therefore $Y$ is the union of the coordinate hyperplanes which is pure of codimension one. If you want a projective variety you can do the same thing with the projective space since it is covered by affine spaces.